# How to replace proxy API url with react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, axios

I am using firebase, react, axios & redux. I have two separate directories: one for the API and one for the react app. I have a proxy for local development which works perfectly, however when I deploy to production — the API call is using the app's URL instead of the API url. I am fairly new to backend development and not sure what I need to do to configure for production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I added this to the top of my `App.tsx` file

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://us-project-info.cloudfunctions.net/api';
```